# Plugin Javascript with Source URL's For Images Using Wrong Directory

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

This is tough and would really, really love some help.

I have a plugin that has a JavaScript file with an array of sources (URL's) that points to a "texture" directory in the plugin for images, but keep getting **404 errors**, because instead of searching images in **/website/wp-content/plugins/die/textures** it looks for **website/textures**, or **website/post-name/textures** and never the plugin.

These work just fine on the same server as a generic html website, but WordPress is not behaving as expected. Here is the code to my plugin:

```
wp_register_script( 'die', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/Die.js' ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'die', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/Die.js' );
```

My Die.js code looks like this:

```
export const TEXTURES = {
    'cloudy': {
        name: 'Transparent',
        source: './textures/cloudy.png'
    },
```

...with many more source: './textures/pngs

The Die plugin directory structure looks like this:

- includes
- textures
- die.php

Any input or help would be sincerely appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you enqueue your js you need to localize your your variables from php like this:

```
wp_localize_script( 'die', 'dievars', array('path' => plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)) );
```

You can access this "path" in your js as this:

```
export const TEXTURES = {
    'cloudy': {
        name: 'Transparent',
        source: dievars.path + 'textures/cloudy.png'
    },
```